# Send email with python smtp error 535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful'

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtp-auth

I try to send email with python smtp library:

```
import smtplib

to ="reciever@mail.adress.com"
user="sender@mail.adress.com"
password="password"
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("Outlook.mail.adress.com")
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.login(user,password)
header='To:'+to+'\n'+'From:'+user+'\n'+'Subject:test \n'
print (header)
msg = header+'\n test message \n'
smtpserver.sendmail(user,to,msg)
print ('done!')
smtpserver.quit()
```

It returns strange error which I can't find much about (235, 503) and then 535

```
SMTPAuthenticationError...
     ...
---> 13 smtpserver.login(user,password)
     ...    

    728         # We could not login successfully.  Return result of last attempt.
--> 729         raise last_exception

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py in login(self, user, password, initial_response_ok)
    718                 (code, resp) = self.auth(
    719                     authmethod, getattr(self, method_name),
--> 720                     initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
    721                 # 235 == 'Authentication successful'
    722                 # 503 == 'Error: already authenticated'

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py in auth(self, mechanism, authobject, initial_response_ok)
    639         if code in (235, 503):
    640             return (code, resp)
--> 641         raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
    642 
    643     def auth_cram_md5(self, challenge=None):

SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful')
```

If I try to do it without login method I get this error:

```
---> 20 smtpserver.sendmail(user,to,msg)

--> 866             raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)

SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.1 Client was not authenticated', 'xxx@mail.adress.com')
```

What need to be done fo fix this code?

Comment: are you sure you need the password to send an e-mail? Have you tried without the `login` part ?

Comment: If you mean without login method, then yes, i will modify the question

Comment: has the password or login backslashes in it?

Comment: No backslashes)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing an issue with same authentication the next day. On day 1 when I wrote the code it was sending mails very well. But my company.com password had expired and I had to reset it, but after resetting also it didnt stop to give error. After 2 hrs of back and forth it was again able to send mails now. One thing I changed was I wrote the senders and receivers email ID manually instead of copy paste. rest all was same. Also as i had a function made of it, i tried refreshing function before I made the call with input "smail". Also made sure that the smail input is manually entered. Please try and suggest as to what worked for you.

```
def mailfile(smail):
    #smail='receiver@ymail.com'
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
    from email import encoders
    fromaddr = "sender@company.com"
    toaddr = smail
    # instance of MIMEMultipart
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    # storing the senders email address
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    # storing the receivers email address
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    #storing the subject
    msg['Subject'] = "TEST MAIL"
    #string to store the body of the mail
    body = "Hi DID YOU GET MAIL???"
    #attach the body with the msg instance 
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain')) 
    #open the file to be sent
    # PATH WHERE FILE IS BEING STORED
    filename = "filename_with_extension"
    attachment = open("Abra/ka/dabra/file_with_extension", "rb")
    #instance of MIMEBase and named as p
    p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    #To change the payload into encoded form 
    p.set_payload((attachment).read())
    #encode into base64
    encoders.encode_base64(p)
    p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
    #attach the instance 'p' to instance 'msg'
    msg.attach(p)
    #creates SMTP session
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587)
    #start TLS for security
    s.starttls()
    s.ehlo()
    #Authentication
    s.login(fromaddr,'senders_passwd')
    #Converts the Multipart msg into a string
    text = msg.as_string()
    #sending the mail
    s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    #terminating the session
    s.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem with Gmail, using a similar code for testing, and it was not exactly a programming error. Google just blocked access from an unknown device.